# Drawing on PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, picturebox

in a `UserControl` I have a `PictureBox` and some other controls. For the user control which contains this picturebox named as `Graph` I have a method to draw a curve on this picture box:

```
    //Method to draw X and Y axis on the graph
    private bool DrawAxis(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawLine(_penAxisMain, (float)(Graph.Bounds.Width / 2), 0, (float)(Graph.Bounds.Width / 2), (float)Bounds.Height);
        g.DrawLine(_penAxisMain, 0, (float)(Graph.Bounds.Height / 2), Graph.Bounds.Width, (float)(Graph.Bounds.Height / 2));

        return true;
    }

    //Painting the Graph
    private void Graph_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        DrawAxis(e);
     }

    //Public method to draw curve on picturebox
    public void DrawData(PointF[] points)
    {
        var bmp = Graph.Image;
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        g.DrawCurve(_penAxisMain, points);

        Graph.Image = bmp;
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

When application starts, the axis are drawn. but when I call the `DrawData` method I get the exception that says `bmp` is null. What can be the problem?

I also want to be able to call `DrawData` multiple times to show multiple curves when user  clicks some buttons. What is the best way to achive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never assigned `Image`, right? If you want to draw on a `PictureBox`’ image you need to *create* this image first by assigning it a bitmap with the dimensions of the PictureBox:

```
Graph.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Graph.Width, Graph.Height);
```

You only need to do this *once*, the image can then be reused if you want to redraw whatever’s on there.

You can then subsequently use this image for drawing. For more information, [refer to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx#Y0).

By the way, this is totally independent from drawing on the `PictureBox` in the `Paint` event handler. The latter draws on the control directly, while the `Image` serves as a backbuffer which is painted on the control automatically (but you *do* need to invoke `Invalidate` to trigger a redraw, after drawing on the backbuffer).

Furthermore, it makes *no* sense to re-assign the bitmap to the `PictureBox.Image` property after drawing. The operation is meaningless.

Something else, since the `Graphics` object is disposable, you should put it in a `using` block rather than disposing it manually. This guarantees correct disposing in the face of exceptions:

```
public void DrawData(PointF[] points)
{
    var bmp = Graph.Image;
    using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        // Probably necessary for you:
        g.Clear();
        g.DrawCurve(_penAxisMain, points);
    }

    Graph.Invalidate(); // Trigger redraw of the control.
}
```

You should consider this as a fixed pattern.

Comment: No I didn't assign, I was thinkning calling Paint method on graph will make the image. Can you explain a bit more please how to fix the problem?