# Drawing over picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a WinForms application and can't figure out how to resolve an issue with PictureBox. In my program I use PictureBox as a Child Control of a Panel, and made the Panel autosizable and autoscrollable in order to display large images. Now I need to draw a marker such as circle over the picture in PictureBox. The marker must be always at the same location relative to the visible part of the picture. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at overriding the `Paint` event for the picture box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing on PictureBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539107/drawing-on-picturebox)

Comment: Show us your effort, how did you try to do it ?

Comment: "at the same location relative to the visible part of the picture" -- what does that mean? same location relative to the picture itself? Or same location relative to the `Panel` containing the picture (i.e. inasmuch as the `Panel` defines "the visible part of the picture"). Your question needs a lot of elaboration, both in terms of a code example and being clear about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Not using the panel's AutoScrollPosition would be the typical bug.  We can't see it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I mean that painted figure should remain at the same position relative to the Panel containing the picture. This painted figure should remain at the same position relative to the Panel when I scroll large image with panel's scrollbars.

Comment: Then, shouldn't you draw the figure into the `Panel`'s client area instead of the `PictureBox`? I.e. handle the `Panel`'s `Paint` event instead of that of the `PictureBox`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I tried but in this case I can't see figure painted on the Panel because PictureBox is over the Panel.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Graphics class to draw in a PictureBox, you can get the graphic class from several controls, in your case see how to get the Graphics class and draw a circle:

```
Graphics g = pictBox.CreateGraphics();
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
g.DrawEllipse(pen, 10, 10, 20, 20);
```

if you will use animated drawing you need more speed, in this case the better way is use the event paint and enable the double buffering, see how to enable double buffering:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
}
```

using the paint event you can draw more speed and one of the parameter of paint function get the graphics class of the control, see this example:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    // Clear picture box with blue color
    g.Clear(Color.Blue);
    // Create a pen to draw Ellipse
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
    g.DrawEllipse(pen, 10, 10, 20, 20);
}
```

To draw everytime using the Paint event you need to call in some loop the pict.Invalidate() to to call the Paint event.